# What if you don't want to create dozen classes for AlertDialogs?

Tags: android

I have many different states according to which I need to feedback to User with a message in form of `AlertDialog`. It's just insane to create a separate class for each alert. What I have now is:

```
class FeedbackAlertDialog extends DialogFragment {
    private String message;
    private int action;

    FeedbackAlertDialog() {
    }

    FeedbackAlertDialog(String message, int action) {
        this.message = message;
        this.action = action;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setTitle(message)
                .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        switch (action) {
                            case action: // It's impossible because the int should be final
                        }
                        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class));
                    }
                }).show();
    }
}
```

The problem is that I can't use `switch` because `int` should be final. How to come up with this situation?

Comment: I think you need  **private int action;**  as final??

Comment: But if I would have it `final` I wouldn't be able to change it in `Constructor`. That's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just impossible because you need to use a constant in switch.

Answer (score 0):

use:

> FeedbackAlertDialog.this.action

As far as i can see this should be in the switch.

This same way is used for accesing higher level variables (Notice Setters in a simple model).

in your case you have to first get into the scope of the root object(your case FeedbackAlertDialog).

Comment: Compilator required the `action` to be constant.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT ::**

Try this simple java demo at your computer system:

```
public class CalcDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n1 = 6, n2 = 3;
        int opr = 1;
        MyMath math = new MyMath(n1, n2, opr);
        System.out.println("Answer :: "+math.getResult());
    }
}

class MyMath {
    int n1, n2, opr;

    public MyMath() {   }
    public MyMath(int n1, int n2, int opr) {
        this.n1 = n1;
        this.n2 = n2;
        this.opr = opr;
    }
    public int getResult() {
        //int ch = opr;
        switch (opr) {
        case 1: return n1-n2;
            //break;
        case 2: return n1+n2;
        default : System.out.println("Invalid Choice");
            break;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

---

Do one **Trick** as following:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setTitle(message)
            .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    final int action1 = action;  //  <---- ---  Try This
                    switch (action1) {  //  <--- ---  Use as This
                        case action1: // I THINK,  NOW  THIS  IS  POSSIBLE
                    }
                    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class));
                }
            }).show();
}
```

Comment: there's no error, if you want to use a variable within inner class it has to be final.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14004/discussion-between-siik-and-chintan-raghwani)